# How do I use the Boost libraries in a qmake project?

Tags: c++, qt, boost

Some days ago I compiled Boost ver. 1.53.0 for VS2012. It works fine, compiles fine. Now I want to use Boost with Qt Creator. In the `.pro` file I've included

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\boost\boost_1_53_0\  -lboost_filesystem
LIBS += C:/boost/boost_1_53_0/stage/lib/
```

But when I compile I get 2 errors:

```
:-1: error: cannot find C:/boost/boost_1_53_0/stage/lib/: Permission denied
collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What should I do? I've googled but seems I'm the first with this error.

Comment: Note Qt Creator has decent CMake support and CMake has excellent Boost support.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\boost\boost_1_53_0\  -lboost_filesystem
LIBS += C:/boost/boost_1_53_0/stage/lib/
```

Wrong.

[Read this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs).

Solution:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/boost/boost_1_53_0/
LIBS += "-LC:/boost/boost_1_53_0/stage/lib/"
```

Boost has complicated library names ("libboost_filesystem-vc90-mt-1_53.lib") and in case of msvc it links them automatically.)
If you want to link additional lib, you do it like this:

```
LIBS += "-LMyLibraryPath" -lmylib
```

Where MyLibraryPath is library path, and mylib is library you want to link with.

> i'm the first with this error.

The error most likely occurs because compiler tries to open directory as if it were a file or something like that.

Comment: thanks, it works when i include <boost/regex.hpp> or <boost/config.hpp> but when i try to include <boost/asio.hpp> i get a bunch of errors. what's the cause?

Comment: @ddacot: I don't see your "asio errors", because you haven't posted them, so I don't know what's the case. I suggest to ask separate question about it, or update this one.

Comment: sorry, i just forgot to put the link, here it is : http://s1.directupload.net/images/130608/koyvqpdp.jpg

Comment: To use boost::filesystem, you need to link to boost::system as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
win32 {
    INCLUDEPATH += C:/Users/User/Downloads/dev/boost_1_61_0
    LIBS += "-LC:/dev/Boost/lib/" \
    "-Llibboost_filesystem-mgw53-mt-d-1_61.a", "-Llibboost_system-mgw53-mt-d-1_61.a", "-Llibboost_serialization-mgw53-mt-d-1_61.a" -LLIBS

}
```